# Editing objects out of a video

Tags: video, editing, cleaning

Whilst filming a flypast, a stray piece of material flew onto my camera, wrapping around the lens, and appearing in some frames.

Can this string be edited out of the video?

(I can sort the audio etc... as I made a separate recording of the audio. It's just editing out the string I am bothered about)

Many thanks.

Comment: Generally, this will be very difficult. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: https://youtu.be/gGQuwj_Sl_8

You'll see it in this video.

Comment: You mean the hairs and clothes (I.e. 01:23 - 01:30), right?

Answer (score 1):

In relatively static scenes it's not too tough (just tedious) to either paint out the offender or 'clone brush' using nearby frames. When you have fast motion it gets more difficult. In any case it's usually a frame-by-frame process a la rotoscoping.

If you have a budget, investigate the plugins variously called wire-removal, rig-removal, 'no-strings' etc. which can help automate this.